# Use na_if function in R with negative condition

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I would like to replace NAs in a data frame using na_if in column Value conditonal on column Category. But instead of condition used below I would like to replace it in case it is **not equal** to "cat_1".

```
data_B <- data_A %>% 
  mutate(Value = na_if(Category, "cat_1"))
```

Can it be modified? Equality operators do not seem to work.

Note: na_if function keeps original values in a column whilst replacing part of them with NAs (it does not substitute Category values in the Value column in this example)

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Is `Category` a character or factor variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is directly possible with `na_if`, but you can use `replace` + `!=` instead, or `case_when` + `==`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data.frame(Category = paste0("cat_", 1:4)) %>% 
  mutate(Value = replace(Category, Category != "cat_1", NA),
         Value2 = case_when(Category == "cat_1" ~ Category))
```

output

```r
  Category Value Value2
1    cat_1 cat_1  cat_1
2    cat_2  <NA>   <NA>
3    cat_3  <NA>   <NA>
4    cat_4  <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. Only in accordance with what my original intent was (and how na_if functions), I replaced Category with original Value and Value2 values in both columns:
`data.frame(Category = paste0("cat_", 1:4), Value = (1:4), Value2 = (1:4)) %>% 
  mutate(Value = replace(Value, Category != "cat_1", NA),
         Value2 = case_when(Category == "cat_1" ~ Value2))`

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Maël's answer is the easiest solution, but another potential option is to create your own function; looking at the [source code for `na_if()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/c2a3fca9ab85dd847605c7fda1d6b0b971f9381a/R/na-if.R) you could `Negate()` the `vec_equal()` to create your own `na_if_not()` function and still retain the utility and behaviour of `na_if()`, i.e.

Simple example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vctrs)

na_if_not <- function(x, y) {
  y <- vec_cast(x = y, to = x, x_arg = "y", to_arg = "x")
  y <- vec_recycle(y, size = vec_size(x), x_arg = "y")
  na <- vec_init(x)
  vec_not_equal <- Negate(vec_equal)
  where <- vec_not_equal(x, y, na_equal = TRUE)
  x <- vec_assign(x, where, na)
  x
}

df <- data.frame(Category = paste0("cat_", 1:4),
                 Value = paste0("cat_", 1:4),
                 Value2 = paste0("cat_", 1:4))
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = na_if_not(Value, "cat_1"),
         Value2 = na_if_not(Category, "cat_1"))
#>   Category Value Value2
#> 1    cat_1 cat_1  cat_1
#> 2    cat_2  <NA>   <NA>
#> 3    cat_3  <NA>   <NA>
#> 4    cat_4  <NA>   <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Replacing "setosa's" (`na_if()`) and "everything-but-setosa's" (`na_if_not()`) in place:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(vctrs)

na_if_not <- function(x, y) {
  y <- vec_cast(x = y, to = x, x_arg = "y", to_arg = "x")
  y <- vec_recycle(y, size = vec_size(x), x_arg = "y")
  na <- vec_init(x)
  vec_not_equal <- Negate(vec_equal)
  where <- vec_not_equal(x, y, na_equal = TRUE)
  x <- vec_assign(x, where, na)
  x
}

# na_if() example
iris %>%
  head() %>%
  mutate(Species = c("Setosa", "virginica", "versicolor",
                     "Setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")) %>% 
  mutate(Species = na_if(Species, "Setosa"))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       <NA>
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  virginica
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 versicolor
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       <NA>
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  virginica
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 versicolor

# na_if_not() example
iris %>%
  head() %>%
  mutate(Species = c("Setosa", "virginica", "versicolor",
                     "Setosa", "virginica", "versicolor")) %>% 
  mutate(Species = na_if_not(Species, "Setosa"))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  Setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    <NA>
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    <NA>
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  Setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    <NA>
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: There is a problem that the function replaces testX values with Species values but it should keep original testX values (that is how na_if works)

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion; I've updated my answer to illustrate how `na_if_not()` works

Comment: Updated the question as well because it obviously was not clear

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is a factor or your willing to convert:

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(
    Value = factor(df$Category, levels = "cat_1"),
    Value2 = as.character(Value) # Converting factor to character
  )

# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Category: Factor w/ 4 levels "cat_1","cat_2",..: 1 2 3 4
#  $ Value   : Factor w/ 1 level "cat_1": 1 NA NA NA
#  $ Value2  : chr  "cat_1" NA NA NA

#   Category Value Value2
# 1    cat_1 cat_1  cat_1
# 2    cat_2  <NA>   <NA>
# 3    cat_3  <NA>   <NA>
# 4    cat_4  <NA>   <NA>
```

Data:

```
df = data.frame(Category = factor(paste0("cat_", 1:4)))
```